# How many devices could be unlock by using single apphub account?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Any one please tell me How many devices could be unlock by using single apphub account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can unlock 3 devices by default.

This means you can have 3 devices unlocked at the same time. You can remove unlocked devices and switch them for another device

Comment: Also, if you have a student account, only 1 device can be unlocked

Comment: @GeertvdC Do you have a reference source for this information?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202924(VS.92).aspx. `How do I unlock a device` section.

Comment: You can find all your unlocked devices on https://users.create.msdn.com/account/profile in `devices` tab. Here you can see `Maximum allowable device registrations` also